# registry.byId for widget element added as dojo template

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to access a content pane that has been added as a template in a widget,  but I can seem to get hold of it using registry.byId:

my template -- I'm trying to access the div "map":

```
<div>

      <div id="map" 
           data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'" 
           style="padding:0;">im a map
         </div>

</div>
```

The widget code that attempts to access "map"

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dojo/text!Templates/LandUse.htm",
   "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane",
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, LandUseTpl, registry) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: LandUseTpl,
        start: function () {//I've also tried postCreate but same result
            var Mymap = registry.byId("map");//this is always undefined
            if (Mymap) {
                alert("map found");
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Instantiate my widget and call the start function on my main htm page:

```
...
LU = new LandUse({}, "tool");
LU.start();

...
```

how could I get a hold of this map div so that I can add content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inherit from `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` and make use of the `data-dojo-attach-point` properties, for example:

```html
<div>
  <div id="map" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
    data-dojo-props="region:'center'" 
    data-dojo-attach-point="map"
    style="padding:0;">im a map
  </div>
</div>
```

If you did that correctly, you should be able to access your widget with `this.map` (similar to the name given to the `data-dojo-attach-point` attribute).

For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1wBfAh3dwJxYBD1a3Eb6

Comment: To elaborate, in order for markup that uses `data-dojo-type` to be instantiated, the dojo parser needs to run.  Widget's have a parent mixin, `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` which automatically runs the parser against a a widget's template.